# how to search SQLite3 DB using a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm currently writing a program in Python which I need to search a SQLite3 database, I want to be able to search the DB using a variable, which I will get data for the variable from a Tkinter Combobox selection (GUI)

Below is my table code...

```
db = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS depot_racks(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                rack TEXT,
                rackloc TEXT,
                floorzone TEXT,
                product TEXT,
                serial TEXT,
                status TEXT,
                entdate TEXT,
                servdate TEXT,
                parts TEXT,
                pat TEXT)''')
```

Below is my code for trying to search the DB using the variable which gets the users selection...

```
def search_all_racks():
    selection = rackTextBox.get()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM depot_racks WHERE product LIKE '%selection%'")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        dataArea.insert('end', row)
```

This returns nothing, is there a way to use the `selection` variable inside the SQLite query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the string literal `'selection'` and not the value of the variable `selection`.
This is the correct way to do it:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM depot_racks WHERE product LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", (selection,))
```

This way the wildcards `%` will be concatenated with the value of the string `selection`.

Comment: Mmmmm is it the problem with stackoverflow syntax highlighter? The end brackets seems to be part of a string too.

Comment: @CoolCloud yes I see that too.